# Array length in Metal Shading Language

Tags: metal, metalkit

Can anyone help on getting the array length in MSL?

It doesn't work as expected when I am passing an array through a function, however it's working within the same function.

```
uint arr[] = { 4, 3, 8, 5, 3, 32, 5, 7, 8};
```

Tried:

```
size_t size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])
```

is returning: 2

```
size_t size = *(&arr + 1) - arr;
```

is returning: 0

Shader:

```
float4 testSize(uint arr[], float2 uv) {
    size_t size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    return float4(fract(uv.x * size), 0, 0, 1);
}
fragment float4 testFrag(VertexOut input[[stage_in]]) {
    float2 uv = input.textureCoordinate;
    uint text[] = {4, 3, 8, 5, 3, 32, 5, 7, 8};
    float4 col = testSize(text, uv);
    return col;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unfortunately it's not possible**, you need to also pass the size of the array to the function.

When you pass in the array to your function, you are really passing in the address of the first element in that array. So the pointer is only pointing to the first element once inside your function.

Therefore, `sizeof()` function will return the number of bytes allocated for the pointer rather than the whole array.

Comment: sorry typo, I have corrected the question. Still not returning the proper array size in Metal. Returning 2

Comment: Please provide your complete shader code.

Comment: The shader code does not matter. The question is clear and is not dependent on the rest of the code: How to return the length of the array above.

Comment: It's matters because the code above works returning 9 for me.

Comment: You're right, it's working within the function but not when I pass the array to another function. Thanks, I have updated the question with a full code that is replicating.